# How to paginate search results in linkedin-j (LinkedIn Java API)

Tags: java, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am using [LinkedIn-J](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/) and I don't know how to paginate search results. The following program returns 10 results. How do I go to the next page of search results (i.e. access more than 10 results)?

```
String keywords = "KEYWORD";
Map<SearchParameter, String> searchParameters = new EnumMap<SearchParameter, String>(SearchParameter.class);
searchParameters.put(SearchParameter.KEYWORDS, keywords);


People people = client.searchPeople(searchParameters);
System.out.println("Number of Search Result" + people.getCount());
for (Person person : people.getPersonList()) {
        System.out.println("PERSON ID : " + person.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is:

searchParameters.put(SearchParameter.START, 10);

Where 10 is the offset into the results set.